# Create a personal diary website

Tags: web-apps

I would like to create a website where I can create comments, put tags into it, and search based on the tags used.  It's intended to serve as personal diary.  Similar to: https://txt.arboreus.com/

Is this something that can be done with HTML and CSS? Or to create comments and add tags, do I need database interaction?  I am skilled in Python, but never developed web applications or pages.  Any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to blog, something like [Tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com), [Blogger](https://www.blogger.com) or [Wordpress](https://wordpress.com/) has what you need.  They all provide a degree of customization via HTML and CSS.  I'm not familiar enough with them to describe their finer points, but I would give them serious consideration.

If you want an excuse to pick up some frontend skills without maintaining a backend, then [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com) is an option.  GitHub Pages allows you to host static websites generated by [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com).  This is a popular choice among developers, and is what I use personally.

**Pros:**

- [Many templates are available](https://jekyllthemes.io), especially those geared towards personal websites and blogs.
- Your website can have anything you want.  You can maintain a simple blog, or you can make an extravagant web app that pushes your browser to its limits.
- GitHub Pages is free.

**Cons:**

- You will need to be proficient in HTML, CSS, and Jekyll to do anything more than the basics.
- GitHub Pages only supports *static* websites.  This means no server-side logic, including databases and user accounts; your website is generated and stored as files that don't change unless you update your code.  Some features will have to be added as external services, such as [Disqus](https://disqus.com) for comments.
- While there are [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)'s available, they often require a degree of customization.  They do not eliminate the need for some web development skills.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to keep a personal diary on the web? I would strongly suggest you get a copy of an application like Day One. If you insist on a web site, consider WordPress, SquareSpace or Wix.